# Add URL parameters on successful create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Case:**

When I submit my form that is located on `/jobs/test-lune-f/apply?locale=fr` the create method gets launched and does some checks.

The code will either run trough the whole create method and go the the `create.html.erb` page or will do `return render :index`.

**Problem:**

The problem is that the `create.html.erb` has the same URL `/jobs/test-lune-f/apply?locale=fr` as the `index.html.erb` page.

**Question:**

When the create method runs completely ok, is it possible to an URL parameter like #success to it?

I've tried to do this via the addition of `:anchor => "success"` to the form_for but it also get's added when the method returns via `return render :index`.

**Goal:**

To be able to add URL parameters when the form get's submitted successfully.

**CODE:**

**Routes:**

```
  resources :jobs, :only => [:show, :index, :create] do
    resources :apply, :only => [:index, :create]
    resources :share, :only => [:index, :create]
  end

  resources :apply, :only => :index do
    collection { get 'add'}
  end
```

Comment: url comes from the browser, if you want to change it, redirect

Comment: I just want to add a simple parameter not a whole new URL

Comment: If you use **JavaScript**, then just replace form **action** with desired parameter like:- **action?...&success=true**. Place the script tag inside `create.html.erb`

Comment: you must keep in minds browser and server roles

Comment: Well it's just needed for Google Analytics Tracken

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the location before rendering the page:

```
location=location()+(location().include?'?' '&' : '?') +"status=success"
```

More info about api [location](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html#method-i-location).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do it with Rails but as mentioned the most easy fix is in jQuery.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      location.hash = "success";
    });

</script>
```